# enterQueue, leaveQueue

Tags: java, queue

Does anyone have references to examples for enterQueue() and leaveQueue() for the Queue class in Java? I'm trying to do an assignment demonstrating the actions of enterQueue() and leaveQueue() but I can't seem to find anything in the API.. I already did Peek, Poll, and size. That code is attached here, even though I suppose it's not really relevant.

```
Stack st = new Stack();
       Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
       String element;

       st.push("A");
       st.push("B");

       System.out.println("\fInitial Stack contents: "+st);

       q.addAll(st);
       st.clear();

       Iterator itr = q.iterator();

       System.out.println("\nInitial Queue size: "+q.size());
       System.out.println("It contains "+q+" while the stack is now "+st+"\n");

       while(itr.hasNext()) {
           String iteratorValue = (String)itr.next();
           System.out.println("Next in queue: "+iteratorValue);
        }

       //Peek : Look at value, don't remove it
       System.out.println("\nQueue Peek: "+q.peek());

       // Poll : Remove first value from queue
       element = q.poll();
       System.out.println("\nQueue Poll: "+element);

       System.out.println("\nQueue Size now: "+q.size());
       System.out.println("Queue remainder: "+q);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by enterQueue() and leaveQueue()? These are not methods on the Java Queue class and it is unclear what you are referring to

Comment: Where are these methods? I can't find them in [`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: The question I have says "Write a program named “MyQueue.java,” and implement some of the key Queue methods such as enterQueue() and leaveQueue()." But same, I couldn't find a damn thing on what that is, and I was hoping someone else knew what was going on!

Answer (score 0):

`enterQueue` what is this method?
Java implements the ADT queue and uses specific name for the methods.
If `enterQueue` is the name for insert in queue that is irrelevant.
Queue has a specific functionality FIFO and there is no mandate to use a specific name on the implementation but conventionally we use `add
/remove` for queue `push/pop` for `Stack`

Comment: The question I have says "Write a program named “MyQueue.java,” and implement some of the key Queue methods such as enterQueue() and leaveQueue()." But same, I couldn't find a damn thing on what that is, and I was hoping someone else knew what was going on!

Comment: @AC:I think it is add/remove.If I am correct the terminology is very bad

Comment: I'll email the tutor and clarify.. I've been looking for these "methods" for an hour now, and I can't find anything! thanks for your help @Cratylus

Answer (score 0):

From what you stated about the methods you are to implement, are you sure your instructor does not want you to create the add/remove functions for a queue and not use the ones provided in the library? That is at least what it sounds like to me because I have not heard of those methods either. Considering the name of your program is to be MyQueue.java it sounds like you are to create it and not use it from the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is identical to an exercise in the COMP268 introductory Java course at Athabasca University--and if that's the source then the best answer is "ask your tutor, or post the question in the course Moodle forum after checking to see if it has already been asked and answered there."

That's what your tutor gets paid to do, and what the Moodle forums are for, and it's not appropriate to substitute stackoverflow forums, since then your tutor doesn't know you're having problems and your fellow students don't know the question has been asked here instead and can't benefit from the answers posted here. Moreover, there's also the temptation to "borrow" code that's posted here or in other online forums, and forget that that's not the intention of the exercise--and could possibly get you a severe penalty for cheating.

Your tutor knows about these online forums too...